# How do you cycle through items in a Relationship?

Tags: objectscript

This is the current code:

```
Class %Utcov.Test Extends %RegisteredObject
{

ClassMethod listClasses(ns As %String, projectName As %String)
{
    // Switch namespaces to the new one
    new $namespace
    set $namespace = ns

    // Grab our project, by name; fail otherwise
    // TODO: failing is CRUDE at this point...
    #dim project as %Studio.Project
    #dim status as %Status

    // TODO: note sure what the "concurrency" parameter is; leave the default
    // which is -1
    set project = ##class(%Studio.Project).%OpenId(projectName, /* default */, .status)

    if ('status) {
        write "Argh; failed to load", !
        halt // meh... Ugly, f*ing ugly
    }

    w project.Items
}

ClassMethod main()
{
    do ..listClasses("USER", "cache-tort-git")
}

}
```

First things first: I know that the code sucks... But that's the learning curve, I will eventually do better... The problem I want to solve here is this line:

```
w project.Items
```

At the console, it currently prints:

```
2@%Library.RelationshiptObject
```

but what I'd like to do is of course to cycle through these objects, which, according to the documentation, are "instances" of [%Studio.ProjectItem](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Studio.ProjectItem).

How do I cycle through these? `WRITE` doesn't cut it, and in fact I surmised from the start that it would not... I just cannot figure out how this is done in ObjectScript :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your writed object with `w project.Items`, you got such string `2@%Library.RelationshiptObject`, this string may help in understanding what the object we got, and in this case it is an object of class `%Library.RelationshiptObject`, when you open this class in [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?APP=1&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Library.RelationshipObject), you may find some methods which could help you.
[Here](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_relationships#GOBJ_relationships_inmembehav) you can find some examples, how to work with relationships, in objects way and with sql.

Comment: I stumbled upon this page, so now I have the list of objects. There is one object which is of type `PKG` which seems to be what I want... Now I need to be able to list the files in that object...

Answer (score 0):

```
Set tKey = ""
For {
    ;tItem will be the first item in your list which will be ordered by OREF
    Set tItem = project.Items.GetNext(.tKey)
    Quit:(tKey = "")
    ;Do whatever you want with tItem
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your answer by using the appropriate code formatting.